# Config filebeat only to read last 5 day of log files

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, filebeat

I have several log files in following directory format in "logs" folder

```
2019-10-22
2019-10-21
2019-10-20
2019-10-19
```

above each folder have Error.log file. I want to read those Error.log files from `2019-10-20` to above from filebeat and push to elastic serch. how can I do this using filebeat.yml

this is my filebaet.yml section

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - d:\sites\*\logs\*\Error.log

  fields:
    level: error
    application: cms

  ### Multiline options
  multiline.pattern: '^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})'
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after
  pipeline: logpipeline
```

Comment: No need to set "enabled", because  [inputs are enabled by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html#_enabled_11")

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will be a perfect answer. But for the situation, you can use feature `exclude_lines` in filebeat. In your *filebeat.yml* file configure like below and try.

```
 filebeat.inputs:

- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
     - /var/log/*.log

  exclude_lines: ['^2019-10-1']
```

This will exclude lines that starts with "2019-10-1"

Answer (score 0):

finally found this. file beat config allows ignoring file by time. you can use it as mins(24s), 24 hours(24h), 24 days(24d)

```
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - d:\annywhere\logs\*\Error.log

  ignore_older: 24h
```